# Non-qualified stock options tax optimization strategy

Tags: united-states, employee-stock-options

I'm trying to understand the best strategy for reducing tax liability with non-qualified stock options.

**Assuming the stock price will only ever increase**

1. Exercise all newly vested options as soon as possible each time options vest.
2. Hold newly exercised stock for at least a year.
3. Sell stock after you've held it for the year.

*My question is the above different at all from the following*:

1. Cashless sell all newly vested options as soon as possible each time options vest.
2. Use proceeds from cashless sale immediately to buy the stock at FMV and hold for at least a year.
3. Sell stock after you've held it for the year.

In both would seems:

- FMV at exercise minus strike price will be taxed at ordinary income and
- FMV on sale date minus FMV on exercise date will be taxed at the long term gains rate

Comment: Does it allow early exercise (i.e. exercise before vesting)?

Comment: @user102008 You mean exercise before _expiry_?

Comment: @DStanley: no, I mean exercise before vesting

Comment: @user102008 well, before vesting you don't own them, so you can't exercise or sell them.  But OP is talking about selling/exercising when they vest, not before.

Comment: @DStanley: Some private stock options do allow exercise before vesting, and there is a clause that they have the right to buy the stock back from you at exercise price if you leave before it vests. In that case exercise immediately upon option grant may have some tax advantages. But I guess you're right that OP is able to see the stock right away then it's unlikely to be such a type of stock option.

Answer (score 1):

You are still taxed on the realized ordinary income if you immediately sell your shares. Further, your cost basis will be *at least* as high compared to exercise-and-hold. Even if the share price decreased, your cost basis would be adjusted upwards due to wash sale rules.

Once you sell the stock for a long-term gain, a higher cost basis would reduce your gross capital gain, lowering the capital gains tax you'll owe. But your net capital gain would *also* be less than what you would have realized had you simply exercised the options and held the shares. So you tax liability could be reduced, but only because your taxable proceeds are less.